# Adding Room Database class in MVVM based app is giving binding issues

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-room

I'm using Room Database in my MVVM based android app. The issue that i'm facing is that whenever i place Database file in code the app starts giving DataBinding errors and all errors get removed when i remove that file. I've not even declared it yet in AppModule file yet and it starts giving error. What is the issue?

DB class:

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract UserDao userDao();

}
```

Following is Dao:

```
    @Dao
    public interface UserDao {

        @Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE userId =:id")
        User findUserById(String id);
}
```

Following is User Model:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int userId;

    private String username;

    private String fullName;

    @Ignore
    private boolean isLive;

    private String createdAt;

    @Ignore
    private boolean requestSent;
    @Ignore
    private boolean isFollowed;

    private String picture;

    private String name;
    @Ignore
    private boolean isFollow;

    private String phone;
}
```

Comment: Have you created the database instance in AppDatabase class.?

Comment: I'll inject it in AppModule.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please inject inside a AppDatabase class

 /** The AppDatabase instance */
private static AppDatabase mInstance;

/**
 * Gets the singleton instance of AppDatabase.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @return The singleton instance of AppDatabase.
 */
public static AppDatabase getDatabaseInstance(Context context)
{
    if (mInstance == null)
    {                                                                           /* The name of the Database table. */
        mInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "databaseTableName")).build();
    }

    return mInstance;
}


    And make sure to use Cursor not User to findUserById

    @Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE userId =:id")
    Cursor findUserById(String id);
```

Comment: I'm using Dagger2 and no need to create instance this way. It can be added in AppModule. And that part comes later, if i add file without creating instance it should not be causing issue. Because i'm not using it anywhere yet